# How to display dates in fullcalendar in different format?

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar](https://atmospherejs.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar) package. My goal is to display the appointments from the database in the calendar.

From their documentations, I have to use [events()](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) function.

I my collection (`Requests`), I have title and start attributes. The start attribute is stored as below:

```
start: 'December 19, 2017 at 9:43 PM'
```

I am stuck at the moment here:

```
Template.appointments.onRendered( () => {
  $( '#calendar' ).fullCalendar({
    events( start, end, timezone, callback ) {


      });
    }
  });
});
```

How should I go about retrieving the date and time and displaying it in the calendar?

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I have tried:

```
Template.appointments.onRendered( () => {
  $( '#calendar' ).fullCalendar({
    events( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
        let data = Requests.find().fetch().map( ( event ) => {
            event.start = new Date(event.start.replace("at", ""));
            event.end = new Date(event.start.replace("at", ""));
            return event;
        });

        if ( data ) {
            callback( data );
        }
    }
});

  Tracker.autorun( () => {
    Requests.find().fetch();
    $( '#calendar' ).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
});

});
```

It didn't work, I tried to remove all the code inside `events` function and change to the following:

```
Template.appointments.onRendered( () => {
  $( '#calendar' ).fullCalendar({
    events( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
        console.log('WORKS!')
    }
});
});
```

Nothing was printed to the console. Why the code inside events is not being executed?

NOTE: The calendar is loaded successfully in the template but empty.

Comment: On a side note, are you using String to store date? OR is that a datetime object.

Comment: @blueren It is string that I am using

Comment: don't store dates as strings in your database. That's a terrible idea. You can't even write queries against it. The _GUI_ should have the responsibility for formatting the date (generally, it should do it according to the local custom of the user, or alternatively it some unambiguous format like ISO). Everywhere else in your code should use the appropriate DateTime type of object for your programming language.

Comment: @ADyson shouldn't it be fine if I can query it back to Date? I am using a tutorial as reference and they are storing it there in String format as well. Here: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/reactive-calendars-with-fullcalendar

Comment: In that example when you see the sample data, they provide the dates in yyyy-mm-dd format which is un-ambiguous and also is parseable by momentJS (which fullcalendar uses to handle dates). But also it's a mock, so there's no database involved. They could have used momentJS or Date objects, but it might have been less readable. Generally when you end up retrieving data from the server-side as JSON, it gets transmitted as a string (because you can't transmit code objects over the wire), but it needs to be a valid, parseable, unambiguous string, unlike yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have been storing the date as a string.

```
var start_date = new Date(start.replace("at", ""));
```

The above gets you a date object equivalent. We remove the "at" from the string as it will cause an error while being passed to the `Date` constructor.

Your template and it's render function should look similar to:

**template.html**

```
<template name ="appointments">
    ....
    ....
    <div id = "calendar"></div>
    ....
    ....
</template>
```

**template.js**

```
    Template.appointments.onRendered(function() {

    // each time a reactive entity changes, whatever is inside tracker.autorun is run again.
    Tracker.autorun(function() {


        var eventsArray = [];
        // events.find() is reactive. Any change to the events collection will trigger the autorun to run.
        events.find().forEach(function(event) {
            eventsArray.push({
                title: event.title,
                start: event.startDate, //should be preferably in ISO format
                end: event.endDate //should be preferably in ISO format
            });

        });

        // Each time some data changes, fullCalendar must be notified again.
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(eventsArray);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventsArray);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    });
});
```

I tested the above in my local test app and it works.

[image]
There is a very good and detailed tutorial on fullcalendar and meteor [here](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/reactive-calendars-with-fullcalendar)

Comment: thank you for your clear answer. I have one question, I am retrieving collection of events using 'Requests.find()'  Should I use loop? or is there better practice?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing more details. Usual approach is to use find since it returns a cursor that can be iterated upon.

Comment: the events function doesn't work after I tested it with console.log(). I updated the question, can you please check if you know the reason

Comment: @sourceplaze -  
I went through some of the basics of fullCalendar. I've updated the answer. The code has some inline comments to help you out with the explanation.

Comment: thank you for your help and time I appreciate it. I am just struggling with one last thing which is setting the calendar to weekly view. Based on what I found online, it should be done this way: `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
    });`  but It didn't work for me. Do you know why?